# SourceTree Terminal not working properly

Tags: git, sourcetree

I'm using Windows 10, [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)
and [Git](https://git-scm.com/) .

When i want to Switch branch by using the SourceTree terminal it shows :

> error: pathspec '3.Building-the-API-Implementing-Basic-Requirements'
>   did not match any file(s) known to git.

[image]

But if i execute same command from **Git Bash** in my project directory, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Why the SourceTree terminal is not working ? Is there any issue to work SourceTree terminal ?

Comment: What does `git status` show you from the bash _before_ you attempt to do a checkout from SourceTree?

Comment: It is possible that there is a bug in SourceTree or that it has become corrupted.  Try Googling for the exact error message.

Comment: There is no such thing as *"SourceTree Terminal"*. SourceTree starts the console program specific to the OS you use. Maybe it doesn't launch it with the correct arguments/configuration.

Comment: It Shows : `$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: @axiac I also know that, but anyway it is not working when i start *Terminal* from SourceTree.

Comment: what `git  --version` says in both terminals? I suspect you actually have different gits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by re-install (uninstall and install) SourceTree. So i think my installed SourceTree was corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I just found out that the Git 2.31 update on SourceTree 3.3.4 Windows causes this very issue, either if you're using the embedded or system Git, and can be fixed by reverting to Git 2.30.2, either configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, have `Git 2.31.1` installed in the System and using it as my Sourcetree's Git version *(not Embedded)*.

Alternatively, without reinstalling Sourcetree:

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Git`.
2. Uncheck/disable `Use Git Bash as default terminal.`.
3. Restart Sourcetree (optional).
4. Clicking on the Terminal now will launch a Terminal/Command-line in the repository's home directory.

In some cases, depending on your Git's and Sourcetree's configuration and add-ons, you can also do this after Step 4 above.

5. Go back to `Tools > Options > Git`.
6. Check/Enable `Use Git Bash as default terminal.`.
7. Restart Sourcetree (optional).
8. Clicking on the Terminal now *could* launch `Git Bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just received a new computer for work, and unfortunately the exact same symptom shows up on a fresh install.